# List index out of range for a machine learning method

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

```
---> 30     cvtrain = train.subset([ a for a in cvtrains[i]])
     31     cvtest = train.subset([ a for a in cvtests[i]])
     32     cvX_train = scale_orig.fit_transform(cvtrain.features)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

`train.subset([index])` takes a subset of train at every list in the index. It is saying that the list index is out of range, however, `cvtrains[0]` -> `cvtrains[4]` all exist.
and they are lists, in each of the lists, the max possible value is within the train indexes...

I'm unsure how to debug this issue and would appreciate the assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you set `i`? It's too high for the length of `cvtrains` What is the value of `i` when the error happens?

Comment: @Barmar `for i in range(5)`

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `[a for a in x]` can be simplified to `x.copy()` or `x[:]` if `x` is a list.

Comment: You must be wrong about all the indexes existing. Put `print(i, len(cvtrains))` before the line that gets the error.

Comment: @Barmar giving me the same error :/ `---> 29     print(i,len(cvtrains[i]))
     30     cvtrain = train.subset(cvtrains[i].copy()) #([ a for a in cvtrains[i]]
     31     cvtest = train.subset([ a for a in cvtests[i]])

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It doesn't fix the error, it helps you figure out why you're getting the error.

Comment: I said to print `len(cvtrains)`, not `len(cvtrains[i])`.

Comment: @Barmar I found the error :P I defined `cvtrains` somewhere in the cell as `= []`